Is there a way to re-link a mesh after applying transformations?
Is there a way to re-link a mesh after applying transformations? I have a set of wheels that I Duplicate Linked ⎇ AltD so that they share a mesh, but now that I'm at the unwrap stage I realize I hadn't applied transformation/scale/rotation before duplicating, and the UVs are funky because of it.
I can most definitely fix my original set of wheels and redo the duplication, but I figure there might be an easier way to re-link them.
Thank you!

(dialog box that creates the new unlinked mesh)


Does this answer your question? Edit multiple text value simultaneously the last part of the answer

Ctrl-L > Object Data?

Before answering the question, you should know that you don't need to apply location or rotation before doing UVs. Only scale matters here. So the best solution is to not put yourself in that situation in the first place.
Now, if you really want to apply every transform or you already did:
Select the objects in object mode and press ⎈ CtrlL > Link Mesh Data. But because you applied their location, they would need to be moved to the right place again.
